# Snowflake how to transform a select query result and save it into an array of object?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to select specific rows from a table and transform the result into an array.

Let's say I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE ID > 1000
```

The result will be about 4 rows having the following structure:

[image]

I need to convert the result into an array of object.

I tried using:

```
select array_construct(*) from my_table;
```

But it transformed each row into an array with no keys like: `[1, 'TEST', 2, 'DATA']`.

I am using a JavaScript procedure.

How to transform an sql select rows result into a variant on Snowflake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) FROM my_table;
```

rather than array_construct.